# What does Java's BST ZoneId represent?

Tags: java, date, java-8, timezone, localdate

I have stored in the DB this Time Frame: any day from 15:00 to 16:00 in LONDON (BST)

I need to execute a program IF when I receive an event is between this Time Frame.

I am running the Test now in Paris (16:22) where in London is 15:22 (so in between the Time Frame stored in the DB).

SO this is my code

```
// create Local Date Time from what I have stored in the DB

LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 15, 15, 00);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 15, 16, 00);

Instant now = Instant.now();

System.out.println (now.isAfter (dateTime1.atZone(ZoneId.of("BST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)).toInstant()));
System.out.println (now.isBefore(dateTime2.atZone(ZoneId.of("BST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)).toInstant()));
```

theoretically now (16:22 in PARIS / 15:22 in LONDON) is after dateTime1 in LONDON (15:00) and before dateTime2 (16:00) in LONDON

but I got that now is not before that dateTime2

Comment: **Never use the 3-4 character abbreviations for time zones.** Those are *not* real time zones, not standardized, and not even unique! Use [true time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format `continent/region` such as [`Europe/London`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London), [`Europe/Paris`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris), `Asia/Kolkata`, `Pacific/Auckland`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As indicated in [the javadoc of `ZonedId.SHORT_IDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS), “BST” is not *British Summer Time* but *Bangladesh Standard Time* ([`Asia/Dhaka`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Dhaka)).

You can check the value with:

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("BST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS));
```

So I suggest using [full time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to avoid any confusion:

```
ZoneId london = ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
```

Comment: IMHO, why has Oracle not deprecated this `SHORT_IDS`? It is a pitfall for most people.

Comment: BST is for Bangladesh Standard Time (used in Dhaka all year round).

Comment: @MenoHochschild, if you read that documentation with friendly eyes, it says that `SHORT_IDS` is only included for old code that uses the deprecated abbreviations, not for new code. You’ve got a point still.

Comment: And yet `Date#toString()` returns... `BST`!