# BST Time is wrong

Tags: java, groovy, timezone, java-time, timezone-offset

With the below code, every timezone is printing the value correctly except `BST`

```
​import java.text.*;

def format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX"
def dt = new Date();
println dt;

SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
println utcFormat.format(dt)

SimpleDateFormat istFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
istFormat .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))
println istFormat.format(dt)

SimpleDateFormat cetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
cetFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))
println cetFormat.format(dt)

SimpleDateFormat bstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
bstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST"))
println bstFormat.format(dt)
```

​
**Output:**

Mon Mar 26 09:04:14 UTC 2018

2018-03-26 09:04:14Z

2018-03-26 14:34:14+05:30

2018-03-26 11:04:14+02:00

2018-03-26 15:04:14+06:00

Here `BST` time is wrong. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Is your timezone database fresh?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you expect BST to be British Summer Time, but in this case it represents [Bangladesh Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst-bangladesh).
Also see [What does Java's BST ZoneId represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570166/what-does-javas-bst-zoneid-represent)

From Answer:

the below code works

```
SimpleDateFormat bstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
bstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))
println bstFormat.format(dt)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using the abbreviated timezone name. Check the following note from the [`TimeZone` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> ##### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
> IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, **their
> use is deprecated** because the same abbreviation is often used for
> multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
> Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
> then only recognize one of them.

In your case, probably the system has mapped `BST` to **Bishkek Standard Time** which has a timezone offset of `+06:00` hours. The standard naming convention is *Region/City* e.g. Europe/London, Europe/Paris, Asia/Kolkata etc. where *City* generally refers to the biggest city of a country in the region. In case of doubt, execute the following statement to get all timezone IDs:

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds());
```

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        
        System.out.println(now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output** *from a sample run:*

```
2021-10-12 12:24:03Z
2021-10-12 17:54:03+05:30
2021-10-12 14:24:03+02:00
2021-10-12 13:24:03+01:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3FlznE)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and found that the time for BST was just right. Adding the offset of 6 hours to your UTC time of 09:04:14 gives 15:04:14. I think you're confused with the acronym of the time zone.

If your timezone database in JVM is incorrect, you can get the British Summertime Timezone by `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");`